# Can I use .desktop to treat a process as a separate app?

Tags: window-manager, gnome-shell, window-management, .desktop

I would like to run a special instance of application `foo` on the GNOME desktop. Normally all `foo` windows are grouped together, but I'd like one instance to be treated as a separate application `bar`:

- separate launch icon
- `foo` and `bar` appear as separate items in the taskbar
- `bar` windows grouped separately from `foo` windows (for example, when alt-tabbing)
- when alt-tabbing, `bar` windows have the `bar` icon not the `foo` icon

I tried to achieve this by creating a `bar.desktop` file and setting the StartupWMClass as follows:

**bar.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Bar
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/home/user/bar.png
Exec=foo --profile=bar
Comment=Bar instance
Categories=GNOME;GTK;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=bar
Keywords=foo,bar
```

I get a separate launch icon for `bar`, but after launch the `bar` instance is treated as just another `foo` window.

It just so happens that `foo` is a GTK application, so I also tried:

```
Exec=foo --name=bar --class=bar --profile=bar
```

...but this didn't achieve anything. I'd also prefer a solution for all applications, not just GTK applications.

Comment: With firefox, this works adding `--class` and `StartupWMClass`. You can verify whether the class stuck by using `xprop`, clicking on the window and then checking the `WM_CLASS(STRING)` property.